Assets Not Loading in Vue and Laravel Project
Hey I need help with assets not loading which are using mix() or asset() project is based on vue and laravel hosted on apache on ubuntu os
So my client's pipeline broke because .git file was deleted by someone, so I deleted the whole folder and cloned again folder was located at /var/www/html/vue-laravel now for back up I only took backup of .env file not the whole folder,
Now I have validified that it's not permission problem since I have set permissions correctly and ran following commands
composer install
composer update
npm install && npm run production 
they all executed fine.
the first problem I had before this was that the .htaccess file is in public directory instead of root (/var/www/html/vue-laravel) since that's where sslconfig is pointing to I tried pointing config to public folder but that brings more problems and sslconfig was never changed so its suppose to be correct and shouldn't be changed
now as you would be able to see that on the website the src attribute is starting from /path/to/file instead of http://example.net/path/to/file which is making css and js not loadup
and for the record I am using correct syntax in blade template you may see in image, I may be wrong.
All the files screen shots are available at:
https://ibrahimkhurram.com/helpMe

What is  APP_URL set to in the .env file?

https://streamable.com/l75xgq
I have tried putting mix asset and other thing but no luck

so as I made my .htaccess file in root folder from public folder I have edit my .htaccess file to the following

    
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex home.html index.php index.shtml page1.php
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://komboy.test/$1 [R=301,L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

<Files .env>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all

and ofcourse its only when in your apache website config you are pointing to /var/www/html/
